# Remove the [tweaks] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tweaks) (x60) is very broad and does not really serve any good purpose.

It never adds value to any given tag combination, since you mostly want to "tweak" a certain thing – and we already have tags for this. Typical [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags […] are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

What *is* tweaking anyway? Is it just improving [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance), or do you want to change some program's settings? Did we mean the good old "TweakUI" PowerToy for Windows?

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Questions that don't focus on any specific tweaks, but rather like "How to tweak Windows speed?" are probably to broad anyway and run into being closed as *not constructive* or similar ([example](https://superuser.com/q/137817/48078)).

Therefore, I'd remove this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's all gone. :)

Thanks for bringing it up and doing your part to keep the site clean!